# How to write a driver program for a recursive function that returns sum of vector elements?

Tags: c++

This is a recursive function that works fine. It sums up all things in a vector. The specs for the driver are: Create a driver function to call the recursive function; the driver function returns the value returned by the recursive function.
The driver function takes one parameter of type vector and returns an Object. 
The DRIVER is giving an error that says "No matching function to call for sumVectorRecurse" on it's LAST line. Any ideas how to solve this or improve the driver itself?

```
//recursive function

template<class Object>
Object sumVectorRecurse(typename vector<Object>::iterator left, typename vector<Object>::iterator right)
{
    if (left != right){
        int midPosition = (right - left)/2;
        typename vector<Object>::iterator mid = left + midPosition;
        return (sumVectorRecurse<Object>(left, mid) + sumVectorRecurse<Object>(mid+1, right));
    }
    else return *left;
}

//driver routine

template<class Object>
Object sumVector(const vector<Object> & a){
    if (a.size()==1){
        return *(a.begin());
    }
    else
        return sumVectorRecurse<Object>(a.begin(), a.end()-1);
}
int main(){
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,-4,5};
    cout << endl << "THIS IS QUESTION 4:"<< endl;
    sumVector(v);
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with "drivers", nothing to do with recursion, and almost nothing to do with "divide and conquer" except for the fact that you should have applied that very debugging technique before posting!! (That's why I downvoted)

Answer (score 1):

It's a `const`-correctness problem.

Given `const vector<Object>& a`, `a.begin()` is a `vector<Object>::const_iterator`, not a `vector<Object>::iterator`. Your `sumVectorRecurse` cannot accept a `vector<Object>::const_iterator`.

I would recommend that `sumVectorRecurse` take a `vector<Object>::const_iterator` because, though you cannot remove `const`ness, you can generally add it!